# Is case variant "N..N+100" efficient in cpu code?

Tags: delphi

I have such Delphi case code

```
     const delta=100;
     case N of
       1: begin end;
       2: begin end;
       1000..1000+delta: begin {useful code} end;
       8000: begin {useful code} end;
     end;
```

Is it efficient (code works fast for `N=8000`), for big `delta=100`, same efficient for `delta=300` or `delta=2000`? Or code is slower for bigger delta?

Comment: Its a constant expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiler turns this branch of code into analog of `if` instruction like

```
if (N>=1000) and (N<=1100) then
```

so efficiency doesn't depend on `delta` value here.
Example:

```
const delta=100;
var
  N: Integer;
begin
  N := Random(10000);
     case N of
       1..999: Caption := 'Small';
       1000..1000+delta: Caption := 'OK';
       else
          Caption := 'Big';
     end;
```

Generated code with my comments

```
Unit1.pas.163: case N of
006761BD 8B45F8           mov eax,[ebp-$08]
006761C0 48               dec eax
006761C1 2DE7030000       sub eax,$000003e7  //if N <=999
006761C6 7207             jb $006761cf       //goto 'small'
006761C8 83E865           sub eax,$65        //else if N <=1100
006761CB 7211             jb $006761de        //goto 'OK'
006761CD EB1E             jmp $006761ed       //else goto 'big'
```

Comment: Only if you now anything about the frequency with which the different values of N occur, can you do some optimization by placing the cases first that occur most.

Comment: Are you saying the compiler would generate different code if the cases had appeared in a different order in the source, @Jan? I doubt that.

Comment: @rob Yes I assume (based on maybe old information) case A B C will result in different order of if statements then case C B A. After all, there is no reason for the compiler to value one case over the other *and* it is a deterministic machine - it does not randomize them.

Comment: Of course it wouldn't randomize them, @Jan, but it would also make sense to sort them to let the case-checking code check each boundary condition only once.